# How can cookies be created on client side without javascript?

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, http-headers

I know we can create cookies on server side and on client side with javascript but I may lack some expertise.

**My problem** : I'm trying to pinpoint the creation of a cookie

**My situation** : I have disabled javascript in my browser and I cleaned all my cookies from this particular website. I did not reload the page. I track the network and when I click on a link, I can see a cookie in the first request.
How is it possible?

there is a caption of the very first get request
[image: Network sniff]

Comment: Do you have any browser extensions? Maybe that's where it's coming from.

Comment: I'll give it a try. I'm going to disable everything except webdeveloper

Comment: How exactly are you clearing the cookies?

Comment: The cookie name `pulse2data` seems like it should be meaningful. Do you have any software named `pulse2`?

Comment: I clean the cookies with webdeveloper on Firefox. I don't have any software named pulse2... I'm as confused as you are

Answer (score 4):

Although it's been some time since you asked this question I'm still going to post this as a reference for anyone in the future.

It is also possible to create cookies with **raw html** by using the `<meta>` tags:

`<meta http-equiv="set-cookie" content="myCookie=cookie%20content">`

check this [article](http://www.willmaster.com/library/cookies/setting-a-cookie-using-only-html.php)  for more examples.

**UPDATE**
This feature has been **deprecated** and browsers are moving away from this method and going towards HTTP headers and the `document.cookie` as noted by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49454925/7380613)

Comment: This technique isn't working anymore (at least in chrome since M65)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use PHP**

(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7) you can use a function called "setcookie"

Syntax: `setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain, secure, httponly);`

Just an example

```html
 <?php
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "John Doe";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
<html>
<body>

<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

For more info click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp)!

Comment: The cookies are cleaned on the client and when I click on the link, I have a cookie. This is before the server can create a cookie